# INetSharingManager UAC

Tags: winapi, networking, routes

I am trying to write an Internet Connection Sharing app using the Windows `INetSharingManager` API. However, I must right-click and Run as Administrator for `INetSharingManager::get_EnumEveryConnection` to return any connections. Unless I run my app with admin rights, the network sharing is not that useful, because while I can share a wireless network, it will have no connection to the Internet. Furthermore, using Run as Administrator (or the manifest code to force this when launching my app) at all is not an option for me; I must do this without needing to elevate my app. (The reason for this is because I am targeting the Windows Store through "Project Centennial", and Centennial does not allow apps to elevate as far as I know.) Does anyone know a way I enumerate the network sharing connections without needing UAC admin rights?

Answer (score 0):

UAC can't be disabled programmatically (There are some hacks but i recommend not using them). The best solution is, on detecting UAC, direct users the way they can disable UAC Settings.

Changing UAC settings programmatically on the users machine is not recommended.